# Is it possible to add two values in an OnConflict clause in GORM?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

Looking to do something like

```
UPDATE `items` SET `book_id`=`book_id` + ValueInUpdateRecord
```

in the `DoUpdates` part of the `OnConflict` clause in GORM before calling `Create(&records)`

I can do it in raw SQL no problem, but I'd prefer figure out the difficult way :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps someone.  Makes sense now that I've done it, but trying to find any info on this topic is a lost cause!  This will do a bit-wise OR in mysql to enable a specific bit, but can be translated to any sort of expression.

```
bookNumber := 32

db.Clauses(clause.OnConflict{
  Columns:      []clause.Column{{Name: "id"}},
  DoUpdates:    clause.Assignments(map[string]interface{}{
    "book_id": gorm.Expr("`book_id` | " + fmt.Sprintf("%d", bookNumber))
  }),
}).Create(&bookItems)
```